# How to force printing until cartridges start to be dried with an Epson XP‑445 printer?

Tags: printer, network-printer, ink

Back in the old days, not only you could print with empty cartridges, but printers always gave you the warning after you could start noticing the problem on papers.

There are many reasons excusing this planned obsolescence. But I want to continue printing until at least I start noticing it on paper and clean the printer head if required.

I don’t think it’s a driver only problem as a message on the printer clearly state that I have to change cartridges or cancel the printing.

I know about other questions, but the problems is there too broad an hence can’t have an answer **for that specific model**…
Please also note I’m really seeking to print in colour, I mean to dry the cartridges **not to use other colours or cartridges**.

Comment: You won't get an answer about this either. Unless you're able to rewrite and reflash the printer's firmware there's nothing you can do about that behavior.

Comment: @harrymc that’s not because a problem exists both in Windows and Linux that it can be solved the same way. And in case of printers all solutions are both different and incompatible between manufacturers.

Comment: @GabrielaGarcia this is something I’m ok with it. But were to get such custom firmwares or custom yes cartridges could be an answers to this question.

Answer (score 0):

When printing from a Mac, the Epson XP445 has a setting called "Permit temporary black printing" which allows you to print in black when one or more of the colour cartridges is empty. The setting is available under "Printing Preferences" in the driver. Refer pg 101 of the [User's Guide](https://files.support.epson.com/docid/cpd5/cpd52730.pdf).

Unfortunately, as far as I can tell, the manual does not mention the same setting under Windows, so in that case you may be out of luck. Try going through all the tabs and buttons in the driver under Printing Preferences; if you're lucky it may be there anyway.

Comment: This is not what I meant at all.

Comment: Modern printers will not let you print until cartridges are empty enough to notice it. The answer I gave is the best you can hope for with your printer.

Comment: That’s why I think the answer is at the hardware level. **Your’re answering definitely something I’m not asking.**